# data_source_id in Azure databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

What is the data_source_id in the parameters of azure databricks ran SQL scripts.

Mentioned in databricks AWS documentation that it is the ID of the data source where this query will run, but if I try to change the notebook of and run the query, still the data_source_id is same.

Comment: Can you post some code? What are you changing & what's `data_source_id`?

Answer (score 0):

`data_source_id` is an **another** identifier of the SQL Endpoint. It's not the same as the SQL endpoint ID that is used for operations on SQL Endpoint.  Unfortunately that information isn't returned by the SQL Endpoint Get API, but instead should be searched via another API that isn't officially documented yet (coming very soon), but you can look into [Databricks Terraform provider source code](https://github.com/databrickslabs/terraform-provider-databricks/blob/master/sql/resource_sql_endpoint.go#L142) how to use it.